# Updating a large table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, update

I have a wide table (80 columns) with 70 million rows in it. I can currently trying to set a foreign key across all rows within the table.

**Approach one**
An update statement over the entire table such as:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE Cx
SET Cx.CohortId = Chx.CohortId
FROM Customers Cx
INNER JOIN Cohorts Chx ON Chx.NameField = Cx.NameField
COMMIT TRAN
```

I was informed this has the potential to fill up the transaction log (please note recovery mode is currently set to simple) and it would be better to batch the updates:

**Approach two**
Update in batches

```
DECLARE @Rows INT,
    @BatchSize INT; 

SET @BatchSize = 20000;
SET @Rows = @BatchSize; 

WHILE (@Rows = @BatchSize)
BEGIN
UPDATE TOP(@BatchSize) Cx
SET Cx.CohortId = Chx.CohortId
FROM Customers Cx
INNER JOIN Cohorts Chx ON Chx.NameField = Cx.NameField
WHERE Cx.CohortId IS NULL -- Do not update records that have already been uplifted to include the FK

SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Does the second approach yield any benefit in terms of the transaction log on large table updates?

Comment: [Take Care When Scripting Batches](http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/)

Comment: Unless you have an index on CohortID, you might find it faster to do batches, but on ranges of the table primary key (cluster key).  Your version will still invoke nearly a table scan to find new rows that need to be updated.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik that is not an issue here. There are temporary indexes in place to speed up my joins and there is an index on the column I am trying to populate. The execution plan actually tends to do non-clustered index scans rather than looking at the clustered index which is fine for an integer column for my needs.

Comment: Ah, wrong article. This one directly answers your question about the transaction log: [Break large delete operations into chunks](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).

Answer (score 1):

> I was informed this has the potential to fill up the transaction log . . . and it would be better to batch the updates

It would be better if it didn't fill up the transaction log.  But the proposed remedy is the wrong one.

You should size your transaction log to support your transactions, not the other way around.

> Does the second approach yield any benefit in terms of the transaction log on large table updates?

Yes.  The transaction log can be reused between batches, so long as all the batches aren't in a transaction.

> increasing the disk space to support that would be troublesome

Yes, sometimes you do have to code around space issues, but coding isn't free.  Spending money on infrastructure to reduce coding time is usually a wise move.

Also if you are trying to minimize log space, consider loading an empty table with your query, and then performing an ALTER TABLE … SWITCH.  Loading the new table can be minimally logged, and the ALTER TABLE is a metadata operation.

This will also enable you to perform the operation in a transaction, and not commit intermediate results.

Comment: Your point about the transaction log being appropriate is very true I feel. The issue would be that the table is 25gb and I will be doing three updates across the entire table. That would result in a 75gb transaction log wouldn't it? Unfortunately increasing the disk space to support that would be troublesome to say the least.

Comment: @AndrewSecondary the size the log increases isn't always directly proportional to the amount of rows you try to update with your query. Each operation done to the table will be logged (on full recovery mode), so it depends on other operations that are trying to modify the table, and the amount of rows they want to update. I've seen tables of 30gb generating logs of 110gb because of a long update operation.

Comment: I'll take a look at the options. This is a one time operation which needs to be completed within the span of hours as it stands. I'll review the options with the relevant people tomorrow and see what would work - but your point about space being cheaper to add than dev time is probably apt.

Comment: @EzLo >>>Each operation done to the table will be logged (on full recovery mode)<<<Even in simple or bulk logged recovery models there is NO non-logged operation

Comment: @AndrewSecondary Also, have you considered using a Clustured Columnstore instead of a rowstore table?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes we did in-fact use a clustered columnstore for a short while, however the system is heavily transactional and it caused some deadlocking issues. The system was performing incredibly quickly though with the clustered columnstore.